# TypeLoadException using DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I'm using a third party library developped in C++ Win32 with a C# x86 application.

I make differents calls to this library that all succeed except one.

The call contains a complicated signature.
Here is the C++ signature:

```
ER_CODE KMAPI CLGetMeasData(DEVICE_HANDLE hDevice, CL_COLORSPACE Type, CL_MEASDATA* pColor);
```

Here is all defines to understand the signature

```
typedef int                 int32_km;           //!< 32bit(signed)
typedef int32_km ER_CODE;

#define KMAPI __stdcall     //!< stdcall (for Windows OS)

typedef void* DEVICE_HANDLE;

/*!
 * The enumeration of color space
 */
typedef enum eCL_COLORSPACE
{
    CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY          = 0,    //!< Ev, x, y
    CL_COLORSPACE_EVUV,                 //!< Ev, uf, vf
    CL_COLORSPACE_EVTCPJISDUV,          //!< Ev, Correlated color temperature Tcp(JIS), delta uv
    CL_COLORSPACE_EVTCPDUV,             //!< Ev, Correlated color temperature Tcp, delta uv
    CL_COLORSPACE_EVDWPE,               //!< Ev, Dominant wavelength, Excitation purity
    CL_COLORSPACE_XYZ,                  //!< X, Y, Z
    CL_COLORSPACE_RENDERING,            //!< Color Rendering Index (Ra, R1 to R15)
    CL_COLORSPACE_PW,                   //!< Peak wavelength
    CL_COLORSPACE_SPC,                  //!< Illuminance spectral data
    CL_COLORSPACE_SCOTOPIC,             //!< Ev, Ev', S/P ratio
    CL_COLORSPACE_NUM,

    CL_COLORSPACE_FIRST = CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY,
    CL_COLORSPACE_LAST = CL_COLORSPACE_SCOTOPIC,
    CL_COLORSPACE_DEFAULT = CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY  
}
CL_COLORSPACE;

//--------------------
// Measurement data
//--------------------
/*!
 * The structure of Evxy data
 */
typedef struct tCL_EvxyDATA{
    float Ev;           //!< Ev
    float x;            //!< x
    float y;            //!< y
}
CL_EvxyDATA;

/*!
 * instrument information structure
 */
typedef struct tCL_EvuvDATA{
    float Ev;           //!< Ev
    float u;            //!< uf
    float v;            //!< vf
}
CL_EvuvDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of Ev/Correlated color temperature/delta uv data
 */
typedef struct tCL_EvTduvDATA{
    float Ev;           //!< Ev data
    float T;            //!< Correlated color temperature
    float duv;          //!< delta uv
}
CL_EvTduvDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of Ev/Dominant wavelength/Excitation purity data
 */
typedef struct tCL_EvDWPeDATA{
    float Ev;           //!< Ev data
    float DW;           //!< Dominant wavelength
    float Pe;           //!< Excitation purity
}
CL_EvDWPeDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of color rendering index
 */
typedef struct tCL_RenderingDATA{
    float Data[CL_RENDERING_LEN];           //!< The color rendering index
}
CL_RenderingDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of Peak wavelength
 */
typedef struct tCL_PWDATA{
    float PeakWave;     //!< Peak wavelength
}
CL_PWDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of illuminance spectral data
 */
typedef struct tCL_SPCDATA
{
    real        Data[IRRADIANCE_LEN];           //!< Illuminance spectral data
}
CL_SPCDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of XYZ data
 */
typedef struct tCL_XYZDATA{
    float X;            //!< X
    float Y;            //!< Y
    float Z;            //!< Z
}
CL_XYZDATA;

/*!
 * The structure of Scotopic lux data
 */
typedef struct tCL_CL_ScotopicDATA{
    float Ev;           //!< Ev  Photopic lux data
    float Es;           //!< Ev' Scotopic lux data
    float SP;           //!< S/P ratio
}
CL_ScotopicDATA;

/*!
 * The union of the measurement data
 */
typedef union tCL_MEASDATA
{
    CL_EvxyDATA     Evxy;                   //!< Ev/x/y data
    CL_EvuvDATA     Evuv;                   //!< Ev/uf/v
    CL_EvTduvDATA   EvTduv;                 //!< Ev/Tcp/delta uv
    CL_EvDWPeDATA   EvDWPe;                 //!< Ev/Dominant wavelength /Excitation purity
    CL_XYZDATA      XYZ;                    //!< X/Y/Z
    CL_RenderingDATA    Rendering;          //!< Color rendering index
    CL_PWDATA       Pw;                     //!< Peak wavelength
    CL_SPCDATA      Spc;                    //!< Illuminance spectral data
    CL_ScotopicDATA Scotopic;               //!< Ev/Ev'/SP
}
CL_MEASDATA;
```

I wrote following code to fit the call

```
[DllImport("libclapi.dll", EntryPoint = "CLGetMeasData", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int CLGetMeasData(IntPtr hDevice, ClColorConditions.CL_COLORSPACE type, out ClConditions.CL_MEASDATA color);
```

with following types declaration

```
public class ClColorConditions
    {
        //!< The start wavelength for illuminance spectral data
        public const int IRRADIANCE_BEGIN = 360;
        //!< The end wavelength for illuminance spectral data
        public const int IRRADIANCE_END = 780;
        //!< The wavelength pitch for illuminance spectral data
        public const int IRRADIANCE_PITCH = 1;
        //!< The number of illuminance spectral data 
        public const int IRRADIANCE_LEN = (IRRADIANCE_END - IRRADIANCE_BEGIN) / IRRADIANCE_PITCH + 1;

        /*!
         * The enumeration of color space
         */
        public enum CL_COLORSPACE
        {
            CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY = 0, //!< Ev, x, y
            CL_COLORSPACE_EVUV,                 //!< Ev, uf, vf
            CL_COLORSPACE_EVTCPJISDUV,          //!< Ev, Correlated color temperature Tcp(JIS), delta uv
            CL_COLORSPACE_EVTCPDUV,             //!< Ev, Correlated color temperature Tcp, delta uv
            CL_COLORSPACE_EVDWPE,               //!< Ev, Dominant wavelength, Excitation purity
            CL_COLORSPACE_XYZ,                  //!< X, Y, Z
            CL_COLORSPACE_RENDERING,            //!< Color Rendering Index (Ra, R1 to R15)
            CL_COLORSPACE_PW,                   //!< Peak wavelength
            CL_COLORSPACE_SPC,                  //!< Illuminance spectral data
            CL_COLORSPACE_SCOTOPIC,             //!< Ev, Ev', S/P ratio
            CL_COLORSPACE_NUM,

            CL_COLORSPACE_FIRST = CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY,
            CL_COLORSPACE_LAST = CL_COLORSPACE_SCOTOPIC,
            CL_COLORSPACE_DEFAULT = CL_COLORSPACE_EVXY
        }
    }
```

and

public class ClConditions
    {
        //--------------------
        // Measurement data
        //--------------------
        /*!
         * The structure of Evxy data
         */

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_EvxyDATA
    {
        public float Ev; //!< Ev
        public float x; //!< x
        public float y; //!< y
    }

    /*!
     * instrument information structure
     */

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_EvuvDATA
    {
        public float Ev; //!< Ev
        public float u; //!< uf
        public float v; //!< vf
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of Ev/Correlated color temperature/delta uv data
     */

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_EvTduvDATA
    {
        public float Ev; //!< Ev data
        public float T; //!< Correlated color temperature
        public float duv; //!< delta uv
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of Ev/Dominant wavelength/Excitation purity data
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_EvDWPeDATA
    {
        public float Ev; //!< Ev data
        public float DW; //!< Dominant wavelength
        public float Pe; //!< Excitation purity
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of color rendering index
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_RenderingDATA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ClColorConditions.IRRADIANCE_LEN)] public float[] Data;  //!< The color rendering index  
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of Peak wavelength
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_PWDATA
    {
        public float PeakWave; //!< Peak wavelength
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of illuminance spectral data
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_SPCDATA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = ClColorConditions.IRRADIANCE_LEN)] public float[] Data; //!< Illuminance spectral data 
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of XYZ data
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_XYZDATA
    {
        public float X; //!< X
        public float Y; //!< Y
        public float Z; //!< Z
    }

    /*!
     * The structure of Scotopic lux data
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_ScotopicDATA
    {
        public float Ev; //!< Ev  Photopic lux data
        public float Es; //!< Ev' Scotopic lux data
        public float SP; //!< S/P ratio
    }

    /*!
     * The union of the measurement data
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
    public struct CL_MEASDATA
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_EvxyDATA Evxy;                    //!< Ev/x/y data
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_EvuvDATA Evuv;                    //!< Ev/uf/v
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_EvTduvDATA EvTduv;                //!< Ev/Tcp/delta uv
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_EvDWPeDATA EvDWPe;                //!< Ev/Dominant wavelength /Excitation purity
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_XYZDATA XYZ;                      //!< X/Y/Z
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_RenderingDATA Rendering;          //!< Color rendering index
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_PWDATA Pw;                        //!< Peak wavelength
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_SPCDATA Spc;                      //!< Illuminance spectral data
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CL_ScotopicDATA Scotopic;            //!< Ev/Ev'/SP
    }
}
```

When I run my program, I got following exception:
(sorry it is in french)

> Impossible de charger le type 'CL_MEASDATA' à partir de l'assembly
>   'xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', car il
>   contient un champ objet à l'offset '0' qui n'est pas correctement
>   aligné ou qui est chevauché par un champ non objet.

In english it says:

> Can't load 'CL_MEASDATA' because it contains field at index 0 that is
>   misaligned or over a non object field (approximative translation by
>   me;) )

I've found the two fiels that makes problem are fields that contains a struct which embed a list of float (public float[] Data;)

If I remove them from the union it seems to pass but I got a stack unbalance exception (I think it is a second problem).

But I need them !! I've made a lot of try playing with "UnmanagedType" enum or 
ArraySubType attribute but no result ok.

I'm Okay that make a big post with a lot of code but I have remove all unnecessary code.

If you have any idea ?

Comment: If I do that i must be in unsafe context. Is there any solution to avoid that

Comment: I've just made the try in unsafe context and I have no TypeLoad Exception. But now I have PInvokeStackImbalance exception :(

Comment: I've made a test size of my union is 1684 bytes in c++ and 1684 bytes in c#, so I don't understand why there is a stackImbalance